# Writing a Rest API inside soap web service

Tags: java, rest, soap, postman

I have a soap web service,which is currently running fine.

I need to write a REST API which will internally call the soap service.

Can anyone suggest, how to achieve this.

Inside the Soap service, I have written a `restcontroller`
Code is something like this

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/restCheck", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<MyResponse<RestCheckResponse>> restCheck(HttpServletRequest request) {
                ..................
                ..................
                System.out.print("Inside the service...");
                ....................
                return new ResponseEntity<>(MyResponse, org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

But when I try to hit `/restCheck` from postman after running the server.

I am redirected to location where soap service gives result.

```
Response is something like this on postman.
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
Web Services
</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Web Services</h1>
        <table width='100%' border='1'>
            <tr>
                <td>
Endpoint
</td>
                <td>
Information
</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Service Name:</td>
                            <td>{http://impl.service.abc.com/}AbcServiceImpl</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Port Name:</td>
                            <td>{http://impl.service.abc.paytm.com/}AbcServiceImplPort</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Address:</td>
                            <td>http://127.0.0.1:80/abc/services</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>WSDL:</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="http://127.0.0.1:80/abc/services?wsdl">http://127.0.0.1:80/abc/services?wsdl</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Implementation class:</td>
                            <td>com.abc.xyz.service.impl.AbcServiceImpl</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Url I hit on postman is `http://localhost:8080/abc/services/restCheck`.

**Note** : When I try to run the service in debug mode in eclipse and added one print statement in the very first line of function, It is not printing that line, But it is showing `[Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.`

**Note**: Url I hit on postman is `http://localhost:8080/abc/services/restCheck`. It gives the response stated above. When I replace `/restCheck` with any other random letters. It is producing same result. So, Basically in my understanding it is not hitting that url. It is basically publishing the soap web service.

Couldn't understand what I am missing.

Comment: Please include more code snippets

Comment: you can use jax-rs bundle from Apache cxf

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the WSDL page from REST Service Wrapper which is perfectly correct. What you need to do inside your restCheck() method is to form an HTTP Request to call the SOAP endpoint, get the response from that endpoint and the send it back.

Comment: So you are basically saying, inside my restCheck() method I wil have to create a soap envelop sort of thing and call the soap service's function

Comment: Yes. And then wrap the response you get from your SOAP call in `ResponseEntity` object which can then be sent back from your `restCheck()` method.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot. I will try to do this.

Comment: Even when I try to call the api in debug mode and added one pint statement just in the first line of fun it is not printing that line. Instead it is printing [Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.

Comment: one more thing the same response is generated for any random url. Basically it is not navigating to that url